# Showing content in Jquery modal dialog doesn't work

Tags: jquery, dialog

I have this simple form:

```
<form id="data_form">
    [.....]
    <div id="messages_box" class="messages_box">
        <p id="messages_label"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

where I put a `div` for dialog messages. And I have this code:

```
$data_complete = __('Data are completed. Please login with account just registered!','xxxxxxxxxxx');
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#messages_label").text('<?php $data_complete; ?>');
            $('#messages_box').dialog({ 
                modal: true, 
                title: 'Success',
                overflow:"auto",
                closeOnEscape: false, 
                buttons: { Ok: function() { 
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                                    $("#data_form").find('input,select').val('');
                                } 
                        },
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    $(event.target).dialog('widget').css({ position: 'fixed' }).position({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window });
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog || ui).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
```

where I pass correctly some content to the `<p></p>` identified with id as `messages_label` with

```
$("#messages_label").text('<?php $data_complete; ?>');
```

but when I show the dialog `messages_label`'s content doesn't show.... Maybe I missed something?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you're missing echo? `.text('<?php echo $data_complete; ?>')`.

Comment: HI haldo! tried also that with echo but modal dialog doesn't show the content....

Comment: Try with: `text("<?= $data_complete ?>");`

Comment: Hi Paul.... tried also with text("<?= $data_complete ?>"); but without success

Comment: I just also tried to add $("#messages_label").load(window.location.href + " #messages_label"); between inserting content in #messages_label and calling dialog to refresh the content of that element node but still the dialog box is empty

Comment: no idea about my issue?....

Comment: At least do you all have a possible alternative solution to pass correctly a PHP variable to JQuery modal alert dialog that would show correctly? Or maybe a different template for modal dialog that would show the content of PHP variable?.... I ask that because if I pass normally that PHP variable to a javascript's normal alert then it shows correctly.... just with that modal dialog it doesn't show the content of PHP variable.... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At the end , I solved the problem using an external plugin, Zebra dialog box and now I am satisfied to see an elegant modal message box.... Thanks to everyone anyway!
Cheers!